# How can I pass the input id with the name and value in redux form?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm following along with one of redux-form's tutorials and I'm unable to find a reference on how to properly pass an input's id when submitting the form. Currently, the key value pair submits just fine, but if I want to add the id per input as well, how can I achieve that?

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/gNxjol3r/)

```
const renderField = (props) => (
<div>
<label>{props.label}</label>
<div>
  <input {...props.input} placeholder={props.label} type={props.type} id={props.id}/>
  {props.meta.touched && ((props.meta.error && <span>
  {props.meta.error}</span>) || (props.meta.warning && <span>
  {props.meta.warning}</span>))}
  </div>
</div>
)

const FieldLevelValidationForm = (props) => {
const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props
return (
<form onSubmit={() => handleSubmit(this, props.id)}>
  <Field name="username" type="text"
    component={renderField} label="Username"
    id="user"
    validate={[ required, maxLength15 ]}
  />
  <Field name="email" type="email"
    component={renderField} label="Email"
    id="userEmail"
    validate={email}
    warn={aol}
  />
  <Field name="age" type="number"
    component={renderField} label="Age"
    id="userAge"
    validate={[ required, number ]}
    warn={tooOld}
  />
  <Field name="favoriteColor" component="select" id="userColor">
    <option value="ff0000">Red</option>
    <option value="00ff00">Green</option>
    <option value="0000ff">Blue</option>
  </Field>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
    <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>Clear Values</button>
  </div>
</form>
)
}
```

Comment: Why exactly would you like to pass the ids of the input elements alongside the field values? It sounds like you are trying to achieve something that can be done in a more elegant way using the redux-form api.

Comment: I'm giving a facelift to an existing system that requires that I send both the id and name for the input to the backend. Unfortunately there's not a way around it. I can remap the ids in the reducer, but that seems like unneeded work since I already have the data on the inputs, just not a way to pass it back.

Comment: I have similar problem of needing id - I'm having custom file input, for which I'm using label and for label I need id to be passed

Comment: I want to add an id for our testing framework.